# Controlling multi usb mouse

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is there any way to control more than one mouse, the first act as usual mouse while other would be treated as digitizer input. The problem is How to register each mouse to be treated differently and how using mousehook without capturing the whole mouse event.

I haven't write any code yet on this project, and I 'am just starting with collecting information and stuck with theses questions. I'm going to use Delphi 7

Comment: You can use the [`RegisterRawInputDevices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function  to register the devices and then read the input of the devices (mouses on this case) using the `WM_INPUT` message , try this [MSDN sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about it, but Multi-Touch Vista at CodePlex adds support for multiple mice.
Multi-Touch Vista is a user input management layer that handles input from various devices (touchlib, multiple mice, TUIO etc.) and normalises it against the scale and rotation of the target window. Now with multitouch driver for Windows 7.

http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/

Comment: But that's just for .NET, isn't it ?